# Why 'pip' is not recognized even if Anaconda path is set to environment variable?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, anaconda, environment-variables

I installed Anaconda and added path in environment variable. When I try to use pip command in VS Code it's displaying error. What I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you open the cmd out of the VSCode to check the locations of the pip which has installed and added the installation folder path to the environment variables through  'where pip' command?

Comment: Thank you Steve. Yes very close that you explained. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to fix this issue. This is the process I followed in VS Code.

Install Python latest version in your local machine. Once completed Open VS Code and next press Ctrl-Shift-p to select Python interpreter. Next Choose default python.exe location C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe